# How to set environmental variables in Fish?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, fish

Guys I recently switched to fish from Bash and I've run into problems setting some specific variables for golang in fish.

In my bashrc I would set them using:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/sahil/go/bin
```

Can someone show me how to achieve the same result using `set` in `config.fish`

Answer (score -1):

Never mind I figured it out.

```
set PATH "$PATH:(go env GOPATH)/bin"
set PATH $PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/sahil/go/bin
```

Comment: command substitution does not happen inside quotes: `set PATH "$PATH:"(go env GOPATH)"/bin"`